# Persisting a recursive data model with SORM

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, data-modeling, sorm

For my project, I would like to make a tree model; let's say it's about files and directories. But files can be in multiple directories at the same time, so more like the same way you add tags to email in gmail.
I want to build a model for competences (say java, scala, angular, etc) and put them in categories. In this case java and scala are languages, agila and scrum are ways of working, angular is a framework / toolkit and so forth. But then we want to group stuff flexibly, ie play, java and scala are in a 'backend' category and angular, jquery, etc are in a frontend category.

I figured I would have a table competences like so:

```
case class Competence (name: String, categories: Option[Category])
```

and the categories as follows:

```
case class Category ( name: String, parent: Option[Category] )
```

This will compile, but SORM will generate an error (from activator console):

```
scala> import models.DB
import models.DB
scala> import models.Category
import models.Category
scala> import models.Competence
import models.Competence
scala> val cat1 = new Category ( "A", None )
cat1: models.Category = Category(A,None)
scala> val sav1 = DB.save ( cat1 )
sorm.Instance$ValidationException: Entity 'models.Category' recurses at 'models.Category'
  at sorm.Instance$Initialization$$anonfun$2.apply(Instance.scala:216)
  at sorm.Instance$Initialization$$anonfun$2.apply(Instance.scala:216)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
  at sorm.Instance$Initialization.<init>(Instance.scala:216)
  at sorm.Instance.<init>(Instance.scala:38)
  at models.DB$.<init>(DB.scala:5)
  at models.DB$.<clinit>(DB.scala)
  ... 42 elided
```

Although I want the beautiful simplicity of sorm, will I need to switch to Slick for my project to implement this? I had the idea that link tables would be implicitly generated by sorm. Or could I simply work around the problem by making a:

```
case class Taxonomy ( child: Category, parent: Category )
```

and then do parsing / formatting work on the JS side? It seems to make the simplicity of using sorm disappear somewhat.

To give some idea, what I want is to make a ajaxy page where a user can add new competences in a list on the left, and then link/unlink them to whatever category tag in the tree he likes.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same question. I needed to define an interation between two operant, which can be chained(recursive). Like:

```
case class InteractionModel(
    val leftOperantId: Int,
    val operation: String ,
    val rightOperantId: Int,
    val next: InteractionModel)
```

My working around: **change this case class into Json(String)** and persist it as String, when retreiving it, convert it from Json. And since it's String, do not register it as sorm Entity.

```
import spray.json._
case class InteractionModel(
    val leftOperantId: Int,
    val operation: String ,
    val rightOperantId: Int,
    val next: InteractionModel) extends Jsonable {
  def toJSON: String = {
    val js = this.toJson(InteractionModel.MyJsonProtocol.ImJsonFormat)
    js.compactPrint
  }
}

//define protocol
object InteractionModel {
  def fromJSON(in: String): InteractionModel = {
    in.parseJson.convertTo[InteractionModel](InteractionModel.MyJsonProtocol.ImJsonFormat)
  }

  val none = new InteractionModel((-1), "", (-1), null) {
    override def toJSON = "{}"
  }

  object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit object ImJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[InteractionModel] {
      def write(im: InteractionModel) = {
        def recWrite(i: InteractionModel): JsObject = {
          val next = i.next match {
            case null  => JsNull
            case iNext => recWrite(i.next)
          }
          JsObject(
            "leftOperantId" -> JsNumber(i.leftOperantId),
            "operation" -> JsString(i.operation.toString),
            "rightOperantId" -> JsNumber(i.rightOperantId),
            "next" -> next)
        }
        recWrite(im)
      }
      def read(value: JsValue) = {
        def recRead(v: JsValue): InteractionModel = {
          v.asJsObject.getFields("leftOperantId", "operation", "rightOperantId", "next") match {
            case Seq(JsNumber(left), JsString(operation), JsNumber(right), nextJs) =>
              val next = nextJs match {
                case JsNull => null
                case js     => recRead(js)
              }
              InteractionModel(left.toInt, operation, right.toInt, next)
            case s => InteractionModel.none
          }
        }
        recRead(value)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: or use [uPickle](http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle-pprint/upickle/) to do the JSON conversion.